# Adjusting product image's Zoom magnification factor in woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, zooming

I'm using the Storefront theme and have been wondering if there is a way to adjust the zooming level imposed on the product image upon hovering on it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is possible using `woocommerce_single_product_zoom_options` dedicated filter hook.

> The hook **undocumented available parameters** in the options array are:

> ```
> $zoom_options = array (
> ```

```
    'url' => false,
    'callback' => false,
    'target' => false,
    'duration' => 120, // Transition in milli seconds (default is 120)
    'on' => 'mouseover', // other options: grab, click, toggle (default is mouseover)
    'touch' => true, // enables a touch fallback
    'onZoomIn' => false,
    'onZoomOut' => false,
    'magnify' => 1, // Zoom magnification: (default is 1  |  float number between 0 and 1)
);
```

Related: [Available parameters details for WooCommerce product image zoom options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63106357/how-do-i-find-the-available-parameters-for-a-hook-in-woocommerce-php/63106864#63106864)

Usage with woocommerce_single_product_zoom_options filter hook **to change the magnification level** *(for example we mill minimize the zoom level a bit less)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_zoom_options', 'custom_single_product_zoom_options' );
function custom_single_product_zoom_options( $zoom_options ) {
    // Changing the magnification level:
    $zoom_options['magnify'] = 0.7;

    return $zoom_options;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

**Before with default magnification *(set to `1`)*:**

[image]

**Before with magnification  set to `0.7`:**

[image]