# Available parameters details for WooCommerce product image zoom options

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, jquery-plugins, hook

Apologies if these are very basic questions but I'm trying to understand Woocommerce hooks.

In the post below, the answer very helpfully sets out the available parameters for the hook `woocommerce_single_product_zoom_options`:

[Adjusting product image's Zoom magnification factor in woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53584936/adjusting-product-images-zoom-magnification-factor-in-woocommerce-3)

Is there a archive of all hooks and the relevant parameters? I looked on Woocommerce and could find the hook list but it didn't provide info on the parameters.

Very grateful for any help.

Comment: Yes 10 is the hook priority (the default one) and 3 is number of parameter passed to the hooked function… but that **was wrong** and I just updated my answer **removing that.**

Answer (score 2):

You can find all available arguments for `woocommerce_single_product_zoom_options` hook on [`jquery.zoom.js` file](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.3.1/assets/js/zoom/jquery.zoom.js) included in the WooCommerce plugin, but they are not documented on this file. But as you can see it's a jQuery plugin, so there is some documentation:

[Documentation for jQuery Zooom plugin by Jack Moore](https://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/)

So the detailed available option arguments are:

- **`url`** - *(default value is `false`)* - The url of the large photo to be displayed. If no url is provided, zoom uses the src of the first child IMG element inside the element it is assigned to.
- **`on`** *(default value is `'mouseover'`)*: The type of event that triggers zooming. Choose from mouseover, grab, click, or toggle.
- **`duration`** *(default value is `120`)*: The fadeIn/fadeOut speed of the large image.
- **`target`** *(default value is `false`)*: A selector or DOM element that should be used as the parent container for the zoomed image.
- **`touch`** *(default value is `true`)*: Enables interaction via touch events.
- **`magnify`** *(default value is `1`)*: This value is multiplied against the full size of the zoomed image. The default value is `1`, meaning the zoomed image should be at 100% of its natural width and height.
- **`callback`** *(default value is `false`)*: A function to be called when the image has loaded. Inside the function, `this` references the image element.
- **`onZoomIn`** *(default value is `false`)*: A function to be called when the image has zoomed in. Inside the function, `this` references the image element.
- **`onZoomOut`** (default value is `false`)*: A function to be called when the image has zoomed out. Inside the function, `this` references the image element.

Related: [Adjusting product image's Zoom magnification factor in woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53584936/adjusting-product-images-zoom-magnification-factor-in-woocommerce-3/53585353#53585353)